# UITabBar with TableView using Nib

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I am developing one application which contains one **TabBar**. OnTouch of a tab bar item I am loading a different nib. This nib contains a navigation bar + tableview. I am connecting the datasource and delegates of the table to the File's Owner and getting the following error. [image]

When I am disconnecting the dataSource with the file's owner then it is responding but the Table Functions are not working.

Any suggestions how can I make the TableView functions working ?

EDIT :

My .h file :
[image]

.m file :
[image]

Xib Connections 
[image]

Still the same error. :(

Comment: Have you actually wired up the tableview in interface builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data source does not implement the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, that's the reason of the error.

If you have doubts about it, please post the data source implementation, so we can help further.

EDIT: a few more checks...

1. How are you loading the nib file? initWithNibName or loadNibNamed?
2. Is the controller view outlet connected to your view? (I guess so, but just asking)
3. Are you doing anything special in your controller's initWithNibName, loadView, or viewDidLoad?

If in doubt, add more code from those methods (text is fine)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using your `UIViewController` as delegate and data source for its table, it has to implements the methods from the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols.

The method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is one of those strictly required in the class that implements the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, so you probably want to fix this implementation.

Comment: Your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method does not return anything. Are you getting the same error?